# React js Project Console.log not showing in dev tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, devtools

in my project even when I am trying to do a normal console.log any where in dev tools it shows console.log cleared. For other project i have I tried its working fine still now. Anyone have any idea how to fix this.

[Screenshot of cleared log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKbtD.png)

Comment: I Found the Issue. I had a babel.rc file added with console.log exception added. Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons for this. Here are some steps for troubleshooting.

1. Ensure that there are no modifications to the console.log method in your codebase or any third-party libraries. Some developers override or modify the default behavior of console.log.
2. Search your codebase for occurrences of the console.clear calls. This method clears the console, and if it's being called, it would remove all previous log messages.
3. It's possible that your React app is running in 'production' mode, which might not display console.log() output. You can check this by looking for the following line in your index.js or index.tsx file:

   if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   console.log = () => {};
   }
4. Another possible reason for this issue is that the browser console itself is not working properly. In this case, you might need to clear your browser's cache and try again.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for these ways.

browser is fine as for my other project its working fine. In my code base i don't see any console.clear added any where. I have my project in dev mode also as I a just started it. I know about the production env disable but not sure if in my code some how I have disabled it some where. I am using parcel not webex so i configured project manually. Not sure If I messed up somewhere.

Comment: Found the issue. I had babel.rc file added with console.log exception.

Comment: Great! 
So now, the console statements are working?

Answer (score 0):

Up to My knowledge Production build removes all `console.logs` also make sure what you are writing to print the log, use `console.log`, `console.clear` will not print the content you want!

[image: Console]

Comment: I am using console.log only but its not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using console.log, try using console.error, console.warn, or console.info to see if these messages appear. This might give you a clue if specific types of logs are affected.

Comment: Only console.log and console.info didn't work. Any Idea what could be effecting it.

Comment: @Abhishek That is because you are running in production environment.